# Does Multiple Imports in Python effect memory?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I have a python script

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import seaborn
```

Now  As I have read that pandas has built-in plotting which is on matplotlib, similarly Seaborn is built on top of matplotlib, So When I import all these 3, does this have any issue on performance/memory as single package is imported multiple time, or is there anyway to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Per https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache:

> The first place checked during import search is `sys.modules`. This
> mapping serves as a cache of all modules that have been previously
> imported (...)
>
> During import, the module name is looked up in `sys.modules` and if
> present, the associated value is the module satisfying the import, and
> the process completes.

Therefore, importing multiple times the same package does not cause multiple copies of that package's code or binary to coexist in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your modules are automatically compiled into .pyc files which are then imported into memory. These modules are very small. It is not a huge problem to have thousands of modules imported all at once. Python does memory management for you.